# How to exploit web browsers sandbox?

Tags: web-browser, exploit, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities

I have read a few articles about researchers being able to use flash or java vulnerability to bypass web browsers sandbox and hack a system. Can someone explain how such attacks work?

Here is an example article [Chrome Sandbox Cracker (2011)](http://www.pcworld.com/article/227620/was_the_chrome_browser_sandbox_cracked.html). If question seems broad, explaining only how one would achieve this will be enough for me to start with.

Comment: Threatpost 2013: [using kernel exploits to bypass sandboxes for fun and profit](https://threatpost.com/using-kernel-exploits-bypass-sandboxes-fun-and-profit-031813/77638/)

Comment: There's no "web browsers sandbox", there's only Google Sandbox which is user-space made. The way to bypass it is to use kernel exploits.

Comment: you can't. i havn't heard of a sandbox breach in years. the last ones were plugin-based (flash, java), which is why those are going bye bye. new ones could be discovered, but they will get patched quick.